# dynamic textbox value multiplying while keyup function in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic

Here multiple text box available...I need to do multiply day rate and no of  day allowed while keyup function in jquery. I have tried to multiply the two value and the output will show in another equal textbox. The output value does not show in that equal text box.

**PHP code**

```
<?php
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vefm_ts_engr_details WHERE job_number='" . $jobno . "'", $dbcon);
    $norows = mysql_num_rows($qry);
    $i = 1;
    while ($srow = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {

        $isql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vefm_engineer_details WHERE ecode='" . $srow['ecode_id'] . "'", $dbcon);
        $ires = mysql_fetch_array($isql);

        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-2" align="right">
                <label>Day Rate of </label> 
                <label class="fonts" style="color:purple"><?php echo $ires['engr_name']; ?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3" align="left">
                <input type="text" id="dayrate<?php echo $i ;?>" name="dayrate[]" class="form-control" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="allowed_days<?php echo $i ;?>" name="allowed_days[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $srow['allowed_days'];?>">
                <span id="errmsg1" style="color:red;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-2" align="left">
                <label class="fonts"><?php echo $srow['allowed_days']; ?></label> 
                <label> (NO of days allowed)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3" align="left">
                <input type="text" id="amt<?php echo $i ;?>" name="amt" class="form-control" value="" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
var rowCount = $('#totalrows').val();
var i;
alert(rowCount);

for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {            
    var allowday = $('#allowed_days' + i).val();
    // alert(allowday);                                                      

    $('#dayrate' + i).keypress(function(e) {
        // alert(allowday);
        var x = 1;
        if (x<=i) {
            $('#amt'+x).val((String.fromCharCode(e.which))*allowday); 
            x++;     
        }   

    });
}
```

[this is the output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LIIj.png)

Answer (score 0):

wrap your jquery code with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var rowCount = $('input[name="dayrate[]"]').length;
var i;
//alert(rowCount);

for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {            
    var allowday = $('#allowed_days' + i).val();
    // alert(allowday);                                                      

    $('#dayrate' + i).keypress(function(e) {
        // alert(allowday);
        var x = 1;
        if (x<=i) {
            $('#amt'+x).val((String.fromCharCode(e.which))*allowday); 
            x++;     
        }   

    });
}
});
```

also use following code to count total number of input with name dayrate[]

```
$('input[name="dayrate[]"]').length;
```

This might work for you.

Comment: use alert on `alert((String.fromCharCode(e.which))*allowday)` to see if the value is as desired. If the value is correct then .val is not working as it should

Comment: Thank you Regolith...The multiply function is working.But the outpout value does not come to the equal text box...Its coming in some other textbox..That problem is still being there..